# How do I remove a line from a txt file in jQuery/javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to get my head around this for a while, how do you remove a certain line from a TXT file using jQuery or JavaScript.

I understand you could use an AJAX method to process this server side, but is there a possibility of doing this in jQuery/JavaScript.

For example, say my text file "players.txt" has four lines:

```
Bob
Dave
Ethan
Sarah
```

When Ethan unloads the window, it should remove "Ethan" from the TXT file.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope... JavaScript is unable to access and modify local files.

Comment: Okay, so I'll have to go about this server side? Thanks

Comment: JavaScript can't modify files on the server, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to trigger a change from JS, but the actual modification of the file will need to be implemented in some serverside code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot perform file operations using JavaScript, as this would be a huge security risk

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is a client-side programming language. and to read a file on the server you need a server-side programming language like: PHP, ASP.net, JSP, etc...

take a look at this question on [web development StakExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) for more information.

Comment: To be complete you can use javascript for this kind of operation, but from a server-side perspective. How? By using node.js. That's the beauty of nodej.js: Javascript from client-side to server-side through database-side (e.g. MongoDB and other database engines that targets node.js)

Comment: @roland - that's completely fair. But when we say Node.js we are talking about a higher layer built on JS. which has a built-in HTTP server library. my answer was more about having simple JS scripting. and I think your point is fair enough. +! :D

Comment: Sure :) That's why I reproduce what you said "server-side stuff" :p